# Mind helping a newcomer who hit their first speed bump?

Tags: java, loops, counter, minimum

I just started learning how to program in Java. Everything was going well so far.. That was until I came across this "bonus" question/problem our teacher gave us to solve as an additional "challenge".

[Please click here to view the Question and the Sample input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr8Qp.png) (it's an image file)

Note that I'm not allowed to use anything that wasn't taught or discussed in class. So, things like arrays, method overloading, parsing arrays to methods, parseInt, etc. gets ruled out.

Here's what I was able to come up with, so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         int N; // number of lines of input
         double length1, length2, length3; // the 3 lengths
         double perimeter; // you get this by adding the 3 lengths
         double minperimeter=0; // dummy value

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the number of triangles you have:");
         N = input.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Insert the lengths of the sides of these " +  
                            "triangles (3 real numbers per line):");

         for (int counter=0; counter<N; counter++)
         {
             length1 = input.nextDouble();
             length2 = input.nextDouble();
             length3 = input.nextDouble();

             perimeter = (length1 + length2 + length3);
             minperimeter = Math.min(perimeter,Math.min(perimeter,perimeter));
         }

         System.out.printf("The minimum perimeter is %.1f%n", minperimeter); 
    }
}
```

*My 2 main problems are*:

<s>1) The program only stores and works with the 'last' input.
The ones before it get **replaced** with this one.</s> [update: solved this problem]

<s>2) How do I **print the "triangle number"** in the final output?</s> [update: solved this problem, too]

<s>So, can anyone please help me come up with a solution that requires only the very basic learnings of Java?</s> If it helps, [this is the book](http://catalogue.pearsoned.co.uk/educator/product/Java-How-to-Program-Late-Objects-Global-Edition/9781292019369.page) we're using. Currently at Chapter 4. But we did learn about Math Class (which is in Chapter 5).

**Update**: Thank you so much for your replies, everyone! I was able to come up with a solution that does exactly what was asked in my question.

Comment: This is my first time asking something in Stack Overflow. So, apologies if I broke a few rules, missed out a few important details or if I did something wrong.

Comment: Please do not post a link to the question.  You should include the question directly here.

Comment: OP: next time try harder to make question subject more relevant to the content. Using "Mind helping a newcomer who hit their first speed bump?" is pretty much useless here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.min(perimeter,perimeter)` will always give you `perimeter`. You probably wanted to do `Math.min(perimeter,minPerimeter)`

Since it's a programming assignment is best if I don't give you the full solution to your second question, but your hint is, in the `counter` parameter of your for loop. Save that when you update `minperimeter`, so that you know in which iteration of the loop you found the minimum.

Also, initialise your minPerimeter to 10000 or higher. If you start at 0, Math.Min will never be lower than that.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely helpful reply, mate. I was actually able to figure out my first problem (thanks to your reply and the one made by @Marcinek). However, I'm still stuck at the second one. How do I save that particular iteration count? (so that I can print it in the end).

Comment: Just declare a local variable before the loop, something like int minCounter; Then, when you are in the loop, if after setting minPerimeter it's equal to perimeter, that means you've just set it, so you can do minCounter = counter. (assuming you won't have two triangles with the same perimeter. If you do, it will get the last one)

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop as:

```
double minperimeter=-1;

for (int counter=0; counter<N; counter++)
     {
         length1 = input.nextDouble();
         length2 = input.nextDouble();
         length3 = input.nextDouble();

         perimeter = (length1 + length2 + length3);

         if(minperimeter == -1){
               minperimeter = perimeter;
         } else{
               Math.min(perimeter,minperimeter);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the smaller perimeter in your variable `perimeter`.

The hint from your task tells you, that any given perimeter is smaller than 1000. Thus initiate the perimeter to 1000.

In your for-loop then you have to store the smaller perimeter:

```
perimeter = Math.min(perimeter, length1 + length2 + length3)
```

if the sum of the edges is smaller than the current perimeter, the smaller value will be stored.

Please note that according to your given task, you have to input 3 doubles within one line.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Solution

Make an ArrayList and add all perimeter to that list and then find the minimum value from that list.

```
     List<Double> perimeter = new ArrayList<>();
     
     for (int counter=0; counter<N; counter++)
     {
         length1 = input.nextDouble();
         length2 = input.nextDouble();
         length3 = input.nextDouble();

         perimeter.add(length1 + length2 + length3);
     }

     System.out.printf("The minimum perimeter is %.1f%n", Collections.min(perimeter));
```